# SQL Server 2000 Client won't connect

Tags: connection, sql-server

One day instead of connecting to the database my SQL Server Management gave me the following error:
"Data Source name not found & no default driver found"

Note it had been working for several years before this, all that had changed was an upgrade to Office (97 ->2000) and the monthly Windows patches.

I tried rebooting, re-installing both the SQL Server 2000 and 2005 clients on the machine but no joy.  I can access the database(s) from other machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to save anyone else who may have had this (it took me a full day to work it out), it turned out to be a registry problem:

Several keys were missing from the following registry path, I exported the key from another machine and it's all working now.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI

Comment: Sorry meant to post this on Server Fault, which I now have - it can be closed here if it's too off topic.